# What is the maximum size of DropBoxManager of Android system?

Tags: android, debugging, crash, operating-system

I study about DropBoxManager of Android platform for crash tracking and debugging my app.

I referred this article. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/DropBoxManager
It describes that "The queue is size bounded and will drop old data if the enqueued data exceeds the maximum size." But I cannot find how big it is. What is the maximum size of DropBoxManager? If it is depends on devices, I would like to know Samsung flagship devices - Galaxy S20, Galaxy Note 20, etc.

Please help me. I tried to find the information, but it is very how to find.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer, here's what I've discovered so far

According to https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218147/31304 it's possible to set the value, quote:

"`settings put global dropbox_max_files 9`
*If you are rooted (or via adb shell - thanks @Irfan Latif) you can issue the command above to limit dropbox files in that dir to 9 (or any other number you prefer). You will only see only latest n events, older get overwritten.*"

We can list the global settings, however I cannot see any mention of settings for dropbox.

`adb shell settings list global`

There's an old version of the Java code online e.g. https://code.yawk.at/android/android-9.0.0_r35/android/os/DropBoxManager.java however that doesn't include the implementation details.

https://gitlab.tubit.tu-berlin.de/justus.beyer/streamagame_platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-x86/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java